Can we update the element of set in OPL Cplex
Suppose I have a set at time t = 1, Damage = {1,5,6,9,11,21,23,29}. The element of this set gets updated at different periods depending on the decision variable repair[n][t]. So to update the element of the set I am writing the Code in OPL Cplex that is given below. But I am not getting results with this code. Please guide me so that I can find out the decision variable dependent time-varying set. The optimization problem has 30 constraints. But I have written only two constraints.
{int} Damage[time]; 

// objective function
max sum(n in bus)(t in time)pd[n][t];
// Constraints

subjected to {

forall ( t in time, rc in Rem, n in Damage){
    (StatusLine[rc][n][t] == 1) => (repair[n][s]==1);
    (StatusLine[rc][n][t] == 0) => (repair[n][s]==0);
  }
}  

forall (n in Damage, t in time:!(t==1)){
    (repair[n][t]==1)  => Damage[s].remove(n);   
  }
} 
}


You mix what is allowed in the scripting part and what is allowed in the modeling part. You cannot modify a set in the modeling part.
Damage[s].remove(n); 

cannot work in the subject to block.
What you can write there is
Damage[t][n]==0;

for a given t and a given n
You have some syntax errors too
range time=1..5;
range bus=1..3;

int repair[bus][time]=[[1 ,0]];


int Damage[bus][time]; 

dvar boolean pd[bus][time];

// objective function
maximize sum(n in bus,t in time)pd[n][t];
// Constraints

subject to {



forall (n in bus, t in time:!(t==1)){
    (repair[n][t]==1)  => (Damage[n][t]==0);  
  }
} 

works
